# terminal previous history command overwrite characters

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a weird behavior in my terminal (bash). When I CTRL-P, then try to insert some text at some position, the following characters overwritten. Not really overwritten but my terminal dont show changes, this is debian 7 with xfce , I tried other terminals ,same effect.

I reverted the default bashrc and profile, but not solved my problem.

Comment: What do you expect CTRL-P to do?

Comment: e.g with [_Konsole_](http://konsole.kde.org) you should use CTRL-SHIFT-C and CTRL-SHIFT-V to copy and paste. Which __terminal emulator__ are you using? (I mean which _"box"_ not which shell)...

Comment: With CTRL-P you can navigate backward on command history !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to read up on the bash help (`man bash` or [GNU's BashRef.html](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing)) on Command Line Editing & Readline. There are a bunch of different commands to edit the command line, and they can be changed with an `inputrc` file too (default `~/.inputrc`). Here's a clip about READLINE:

> READLINE
>         This is the library that handles reading input when using  an  interactive shell, unless the --noediting option is given at shell invocation.
>          Line editing is also used when using the -e option to the read builtin.
>          By default, the line editing commands are similar to those of Emacs.  A
>          vi-style line editing interface is also available.  Line editing can be
>          enabled  at  any  time  using  the -o emacs or -o vi options to the set
>          builtin (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  To turn off  line  editing
>          after  the  shell  is running, use the +o emacs or +o vi options to the
>          set builtin.

Here's a section under "Commands for Changing Text" on overwriting:

> overwrite-mode
>                Toggle overwrite mode.  With an explicit positive numeric  argument, switches to overwrite mode.  With an explicit non-positive
>                 numeric argument, switches to insert mode.  This command affects
>                 only  emacs mode; vi mode does overwrite differently.  Each call
>                 to readline() starts in insert mode.  In overwrite mode, charac‐
>                 ters  bound to self-insert replace the text at point rather than
>                 pushing the text  to  the  right.   Characters  bound  to  back‐
>                 ward-delete-char  replace  the  character  before  point  with a
>                 space.  By default, this command is unbound.

I don't think there's a default key binding for overwrite-mode. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+p is the standard previous history key, same as up arrow here (Linux Mint XFCE). I'm not sure how your bash or `inputrc` file is set up, but maybe you're in vi instead of Emacs mode, or you have a key set for overwrite-mode?

- Maybe it's drawing the characters funny, you could try jumping to the previous or next history item (I'd do a up then down keys) and it should re-draw the line.
- Or maybe you've run some commands that have messed up your terminal display (killing a program maybe), you could try a `reset` command and it should set things back to "normal"